# How do you access the numbering of an outline in a Word Document using C# and OpenXml?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to transfer an outline in `Microsoft Word 2010` to a spreadsheet in `Microsoft Excel 2010`.  I'm using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packing` and `Documentformat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing`

I get the body of the document, and use it to get a list of all the paragraph objects:

```
var allParagraphs = new List<Paragraph>();
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordDocPath.Text, false);
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
allParagraphs = body.OfType<Paragraph>().ToList();
```

But I can't seem to find anything that stores the outline numbering that is next to the paragraph.  Do I need to be grabbing other objects besides the paragraphs in the document to get the outline numbers, if there are any, for every paragraph?

The outline numbering I'm speaking of appears to the left of these headers in the screenshot below:

[image: outline numbering of an outline]

Unfortunately, the `ParagraphProperties.OutlineLevel` is null, even though I know it is part of an outline in the word document.

Comment: I'm not sure what you infer by outline numbering, can you post a screen shot highlighting what it is, and then maybe I can help you.

Comment: @VarunRathore, I have added a screenshot of what I'm talking about.  My goal was to have this be a windows application that takes care of all of these, but I believe that OpenXml may not have the capabilities I'm looking for.  I've moved to vba in the Word document for now, but would certainly prefer to go the C# route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now that I've understood what you want exactly, here's how you should go about solving your problem.

First of all I'd recommend you download the Open XML Productivity tool from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30425). Once you know what underlying xml looks like for a file, it becomes really easy to tackle the problem.

```
<w:p w:rsidR="004265BF" w:rsidP="00AD13B6" w:rsidRDefault="00AD13B6">
 <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
  <w:numPr>
   <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
   <w:numId w:val="2" />
  </w:numPr>
 </w:pPr>
 <w:r>
  <w:t>Requirements</w:t>
 </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00AD13B6" w:rsidP="00AD13B6" w:rsidRDefault="00AD13B6">
 <w:pPr>
  <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph" />
   <w:numPr>
    <w:ilvl w:val="1" />
    <w:numId w:val="2" />
   </w:numPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
   <w:t>Performance</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Above you can see the XML for the just a few paragraphs. Each Paragraph has its corresponding `<w:numPr>` and that contains `<w:numId>`.

Each word document contains many different XML files that act as references to the styles and values that are used throughout the document body. For outlines, there's Numbering.xml.

Each numId here refers to an AbstractNumId in numbering.xml and that in turn refers to abstractNum in the same file. You can get your Outline number from there.

I know it might sound tedious, but this is the only way it can be done.

[image: Open Xml Productivity Tool Snapshot].

All the best!

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("word-wrP.docx", true))
        {
            Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            //Documents' numbering definition
            Numbering num = doc.MainDocumentPart.NumberingDefinitionsPart.Numbering;

            //Get all paragraphs in the document
            IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.OfType<Paragraph>();
            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in paragraphs)
            {
                int tempLevel = 0; 
             
                //Each paragraph has a reference to a numbering definition that is defined by the numbering ID
                NumberingId numId = paragraph.ParagraphProperties.NumberingProperties.NumberingId;

                //NumberingLevelReference defines the outline level or the "indent" of Numbering, index starts at Zero.
                NumberingLevelReference iLevel =
                    paragraph.ParagraphProperties.NumberingProperties.NumberingLevelReference;

                //From the numbering reference we get the actual numbering definition to get start value of the outline etc etc.
                var firstOrDefault =
                    num.Descendants<NumberingInstance>().FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.NumberID == (int)numId.Val);
                if (firstOrDefault != null)
                {
                    var absNumId =
                        firstOrDefault.GetFirstChild<AbstractNumId>();
                    AbstractNum absNum =
                        num.OfType<AbstractNum>().FirstOrDefault(tag => tag.AbstractNumberId == (int)absNumId.Val);
                    if (absNum != null)
                    {
                        StartNumberingValue start = absNum.OfType<StartNumberingValue>().FirstOrDefault();
                        // once you have the start value its just a matter of counting the paragraphs that have the same numberingId and from the Number
                        //ingLevel you can calculate the actual values that correspond to each paragraph.
                        if (start != null) startValue = start.Val;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wow this tool is awesome!  It generates code for you in C# too??!!  You deserve a +1.  I'll likely end up giving you the answer too once I use it a bit more to see if this is going to work for me.  Seems like it will though...

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  If you wouldn't mind, would you be able to help me a little bit further with an example.  I've been trying to write C# code specific to the example above, where the outlining is tied with the Heading# styles.  I'm having trouble finding the correlation between the different parts (or .xml) files.  If you have experience with this, would you mind showing me how I would obtain the outline numbering for each of the paragraphs in the example I gave a screen shot for?

Comment: what is the license for this tool, is it free for commercial use?

Comment: @SaadA you can find your an answer to question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280260/what-license-is-open-xml-sdk-2-0-released-with

Answer (score 1):

I found @varun-rathore 's answer to be very helpful in figuring out this issue today. However, my numbering scheme was very complex and I saw the task of calculating the string via NumberingLevelReference to be very daunting. I was able to solve this by installing the following nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXmlPowerTools

Once I had done that, I was able to get the numbering as follows:

```
var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(doc.InputStream, false);

var mdp = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
var xDoc = mdp.GetXDocument();
var paragraphs = xDoc.Descendants(W.p);

foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
{
    var listItem = ListItemRetriever.RetrieveListItem(wordDoc, paragraph);
}
```

Comment: It works with XElement and not openxml sdk's Paragpaph unfortunately